# Copying a jar from package to a resource folder of a web project using Maven

Tags: maven

I have 2 java projects which are Maven projects.

One is a desktop app which has a plugin (maven-assembly-plugin) that I am using to 'package' all the dependencies that this application requires into one large jar.  When this project is packaged (i.e. mvn clean package), it creates two jar files in the target folder.  One of the jar file (childApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) is a smaller which doesnt have the dependencies embeded and the other jar file (childApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar) is a larger file that has all the dependencies in it.

My other project is a web-based project and it creates a war file after it is packaged.  I require the (childApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar) file to copied to the resource folder of the web based project.  More specifically, the jar file needs to be copied to the {webApp}\WEB-INF\classes folder.

How can I achieve this using Maven?

I have tried putting these two projects under a parent multi module project where I have the childApp packaged first and having a the webApp have a dependency on this childApp.  This kind of works except it is copying the (childApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) file into the {webApp}\WEB-INF\lib folder.  I can handle the file location being different from what I ideally wanted but I cant seem to get Maven to include the other large (childApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar) file into {webApp}\WEB-INF\lib folder.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

ps: my web-app project is essentially a JNLP project.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding an additional dependency for the larger jar like the following:

```
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>some.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>childApp</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</type>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
```